# JavaFX - TableView - Changes of field and fields of that field

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm in the following situation. I have a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) populated with data from the model class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
    private StringProperty someText;
    private Bar someObject;

    // getters, setters and properties dropped for clarity
}
```

This class has a field of the type `Bar`:

```
public class Bar {
    private StringProperty someText;

    // getters, setters and properties dropped for clarity
}
```

One of the columns must display the text from `Bar`'s someText. So I bound that StringProperty to the column.

But the table should also be updated when the entire Bar object in Foo is replaced by another one. So I made an ObjectProperty in Foo that contained Bar and bound that property to the column. Of course, now it doesn't listen anymore to change in `Bar`'s someText.

How do I get the "combination" of these solutions, so the table listens to changes both of the object itself and it's fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just the JavaFX API, you can do

```
TableColumn<Foo, String> barColumn = new TableColumn<>("Bar");

barColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    Bindings.selectString(cellData.getValue().barProperty(), "someText"));
```

I don't really like that part of the API for a couple of reasons. First, there is no compile-time checking: you just provide the name of the property as a String, so if you have a typo it just shows up at runtime. Second, if `foo.getBar()` returns `null` (which it will in a table cell), this generates a bunch of warnings to stderr. These are just annoying (they don't stop anything from running), and really shouldn't be there because this is a supported use case according to the API docs. However, it will work.

---

For a more robust and less legacy-style implementation, you can use Tomas Mikula's [ReactFX library](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX), version 2.0 or later, which includes support for bindings like this. Using that library you would do

```
barColumns.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    Val.flatMap(cellData.getValue().barProperty(), Bar::someTextProperty));
```

This has compile-time checking and type checking etc, and no spurious warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You can select a value through a multi-level hierarchy using [`Bindings.select`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#select-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-java.lang.String...-). This allows you to create a single `cellValueFactory` class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class NestedPropertyValueFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>> {

    private final String[] steps;
    private final PropertyValueFactory firstStepSelector;

    public NestedPropertyValueFactory(String... properties) {
        firstStepSelector = new PropertyValueFactory<>(properties[0]);
        this.steps = Arrays.copyOfRange(properties, 1, properties.length);
    }

    /**
     * @param property a string containing the names of the properties seperated
     * by '.'. (For easy use from fxml file)
     */
    public NestedPropertyValueFactory(@NamedArg("property") String property) {
        this(property.split("\\."));
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<T> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T> param) {
        // use PropertyValueFactory for first step and Bindings.select for
        // additonal steps.
        return Bindings.select(firstStepSelector.call(param), steps);
    }

}
```

Note that if any intermediate step yields `null`, you'll get warnings in `System.err`.

Also with this class you need to use property methods that adhere the naming conventions, i.e. the names of the methods should be `someObjectProperty` and `someTextProperty` in this case. This allows you to use the class similar to `PropertyValueFactory`:

```
column.setCellValueFactory(new NestedPropertyValueFactory<>("someObject", "someText"));
```

or

```
column.setCellValueFactory(new NestedPropertyValueFactory<>("someObject.someText"));
```